# How to inherit click method of <a> in Odoo Website

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-11

I want to inherit click function of below shown `<a>` tag and I want to addition my code when this will be clicked.

So how can I do it?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you use Backbone Js?